Zoom not working properly
I was working on a project in Blender and all of the sudden my zoom stopped working. When i try to scroll down it zooms out but when i try to scroll up it makes me zoom with the cursor.
I've tried some solutions to similar problems but none worked


Does this answer your question? Why does the zoom sometimes stop at a point?

Tried the listed solutions but didnt work

Try Shift C? Try orthogonal perspective?

Tried and didnt work, also closed the project and tried to see if it was back to default but it wasnt.

Found the answer! Basically i just had to reset my preferences. Not sure what i activated to make the zoom react that way but reset solved it.
